# NPM Install Error: Fetch Failed

Tags: node.js, npm

I get Fetch Failed error, when I'm installing anything using npm.

I don't have any proxy. I used these answers already:
[Node.js npm install express failed to fetch from registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025719/node-js-npm-install-express-failed-to-fetch-from-registry)

Here is npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'async' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.33
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
6 verbose cache add [ 'async', null ]
7 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="async" args=["async",null]
8 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
8 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
8 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
8 verbose parsed url   host: null,
8 verbose parsed url   port: null,
8 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
8 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
8 verbose parsed url   search: null,
8 verbose parsed url   query: null,
8 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'async',
8 verbose parsed url   path: 'async',
8 verbose parsed url   href: 'async' }
9 silly lockFile b7e04b33-async async
10 verbose lock async C:\Users\Praca\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\b7e04b33-async.lock
11 silly lockFile b7e04b33-async async
12 silly lockFile b7e04b33-async async
13 verbose addNamed [ 'async', '' ]
14 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
15 silly lockFile f9113900-async async@
16 verbose lock async@ C:\Users\Praca\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\f9113900-async.lock
17 silly addNameRange { name: 'async', range: '*', hasData: false }
18 verbose request where is /async
19 verbose request registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
20 verbose request id 96f2dbe6e8964e6a
21 verbose url raw /async
22 verbose url resolving [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/', './async' ]
23 verbose url resolved http://registry.npmjs.org/async
24 verbose request where is http://registry.npmjs.org/async
25 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 17:17:53
26 verbose etag "AFEQ6U5Q5WJTJ8GNUW0RFGL1K"
27 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/async
28 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
29 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 17:18:06
30 verbose etag "AFEQ6U5Q5WJTJ8GNUW0RFGL1K"
31 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/async
32 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
33 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 17:19:08
34 verbose etag "AFEQ6U5Q5WJTJ8GNUW0RFGL1K"
35 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/async
36 silly registry.get cb [ 304, undefined ]
37 verbose etag http://registry.npmjs.org/async from cache
38 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'async', range: '*', hasData: true }
39 silly addNameRange versions [ 'async',
39 silly addNameRange   [ '0.1.0',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.1',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.2',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.3',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.4',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.5',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.6',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.7',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.8',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.9',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.10',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.11',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.12',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.13',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.14',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.15',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.16',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.17',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.18',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.19',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.20',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.21',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.1.22',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.0',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.1',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.2',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.3',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.4',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.5',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.6',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.7',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.8',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.9',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.2.10',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.3.0',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.4.0',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.4.1',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.5.0',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.6.0',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.6.1',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.6.2',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.7.0',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.8.0',
39 silly addNameRange     '0.9.0' ] ]
40 verbose addNamed [ 'async', '0.9.0' ]
41 verbose addNamed [ '0.9.0', '0.9.0' ]
42 silly lockFile 9a58a886-async-0-9-0 async@0.9.0
43 verbose lock async@0.9.0 C:\Users\Praca\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\9a58a886-async-0-9-0.lock
44 silly lockFile 10c57a45--npmjs-org-async-async-0-9-0-tgz http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz
45 verbose lock http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz C:\Users\Praca\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\10c57a45--npmjs-org-async-async-0-9-0-tgz.lock
46 verbose addRemoteTarball [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz',
46 verbose addRemoteTarball   'ac3613b1da9bed1b47510bb4651b8931e47146c7' ]
47 info retry fetch attempt 1 at 17:19:10
48 verbose fetch to= C:\Users\Praca\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7404-pYmejuoz\registry.npmjs.org\async\-\async-0.9.0.tgz
49 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz
50 error fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz
51 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
52 info retry fetch attempt 2 at 17:19:22
53 verbose fetch to= C:\Users\Praca\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7404-pYmejuoz\registry.npmjs.org\async\-\async-0.9.0.tgz
54 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz
55 error fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz
56 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
57 info retry fetch attempt 3 at 17:20:25
58 verbose fetch to= C:\Users\Praca\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7404-pYmejuoz\registry.npmjs.org\async\-\async-0.9.0.tgz
59 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz
60 error fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz
61 silly lockFile 10c57a45--npmjs-org-async-async-0-9-0-tgz http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz
62 silly lockFile 10c57a45--npmjs-org-async-async-0-9-0-tgz http://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.9.0.tgz
63 silly lockFile 9a58a886-async-0-9-0 async@0.9.0
64 silly lockFile 9a58a886-async-0-9-0 async@0.9.0
65 silly lockFile f9113900-async async@
66 silly lockFile f9113900-async async@
67 error network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
67 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
67 error network and is related to network connectivity.
67 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
67 error network
67 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
67 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
68 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
69 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "async"
70 error cwd E:\GitHub\NodeServerManager\NSM\NodeServerManager
71 error node -v v0.10.33
72 error npm -v 1.4.28
73 error syscall getaddrinfo
74 error code ENOTFOUND
75 error errno ENOTFOUND
76 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having networking issues on your computer. The ENOTFOUND message is an indicator that your networking might be having issues right now.

I'd wait a while and re-try. You should be good to go =)