# Installing Express through Node.js throws fetching and tunneling error

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node.js and I was following a tutorial for learning React JS where the requirement was to install Express. The detailed execution/installation steps are below.
I created a folder called HelloReact on desktop, and have a created package.json as well, then I ran the following commands using GitBash:
***npm install express@4 --save.***
After running the above command I got the following error message:

*npm WARN package.json react-test@1.0.0 No repository field.*

*npm WARN package.json react-test@1.0.0 No README data*

*npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.13.3.tgz*

*npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error*

and the bash command line was terminated

I also tried searching for a solution on Google, but in vain. Also was not able to find npm-debug.log file as most of the solution were related to details mentioned in the log.
Please do help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025719/node-js-npm-install-express-failed-to-fetch-from-registry

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["message failed to fetch from registry" while trying to install any module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/message-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-while-trying-to-install-any-module)